# ElectronJS no shadoow when window is transparent

Tags: css, reactjs, electron

I'm new to ElectronJs and I finally figured out how to get rounded corners.

However, now that I got that working, I noticed I **lost the shadows on my window, why**?

Below you can find the entire main.js file for the electron specific code.

```
const electron = require("electron");
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const path = require("path");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 680,
    frame: false,
    transparent: true,
    hasShadow: true
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html")}`
  );
  if (isDev) {
    // Open the DevTools.
    //BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension('<location to your react chrome extension>');
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }
  mainWindow.on("closed", () => (mainWindow = null));
}

app.on("ready", () => {
  createWindow();
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

});
```

[image]

Comment: The shadow should come from the popup, can we see the code for your popup?

Comment: @SydneyY added to OP

Answer (score 1):

So this is a known limitation of ElectronJS, according to their docs, and it's because of the "transparent = true" that you set:

"On Mac, the native window shadow will not be shown on a transparent window."

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#limitations

Comment: But this is on Windows 10

Comment: I know they don't say it in the docs, I'm making an educated guess here, but the "transparent" part seems to be just that, so the window is actually full-size and therefore wouldn't throw a shadow. And the inner window that you've created can't throw a shadow on something transparent. It doesn't seem like a great feature quite yet.